# java multiplication chart of a number using method

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am working on an assignment. Can any one help me why I cant get the out put the assignments asks?

**The Question is:** Write a method that receives an integer as parameter and prints the multiplication chart of that number as shown in the example print. Method name shall be count.

You do NOT need to write the whole program, just the method that prints the chart.

Example output

```
Type a number: 5
Multiplication chart of the number 5
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
```

**My method looks like this**

```
private static void count(int num) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int result=1;
    System.out.print("Type a number: ");
    num = reader.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1; i<=10;i++) {
        result=num*i;
        System.out.println("Multiplication chart of the number "+num);
        System.out.println(result);


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly is not working ? And please try to format carefully the code in your question. This will help a lot in having good attention for your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You take `num` as a parameter to your function, but you replace it with what the user types here:

  ```
  num = reader.nextInt();
  ```
- You print *Multiplication chart of the number* in the `for` loop instead of outside (and so, it will be printed 10 times instead of just one).

If you just correct these two things, your code should be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert the number:");
        print(input.nextInt(),10);
    }

    private static void print(int number,int count){
        System.out.println("Multiplication chart of the number "+number);
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.println(i*number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd personally increment it instead of multiplying it each time: `int iOrig = number; for(...) { number += iOrig; System.out.println(number);  }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just the method use the following:

```
private static void count(int num) {
    int result=1;
    System.out.println("Multiplication chart of the number "+num);
    for(int i = 1; i<=10;i++) {
        result=num*i;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

and the main function should call for the method count(num);